# Control Unity3d Scenes with Android studio button click(Intents)

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I imported a unity3d project having 3 scenes into android studio. I have 3 buttons in native and I need to Intent to corresponding scenes when I click buttons.

[image: sample image for intent to android button to unity scene]

[image: sample image 2]

Answer (score 0):

Unity does not use intents. Indeed, Unity game is like one huge plugin in an android app. You can send commands from Android Studio to Unity game using `SendMessage("TargetObject", "TargetMethod");` (or `UnitySendMessage`, I don't remember the exact name of the method)

Of course, in Unity you should have a script on `TargetObject` that implements the `TargetMethod()`

Comment: But I exported unity source code to android studio. Now i'm working with android studio. When I click button I need to view the scene. Now I can move to UnityPlayerActivity.java, but it shows only one scene. I need to set different targets for different button clicks......................."I need to Control unity 3d Scenes from android studio buttons."....

Comment: do you still have unity project? you can update unity project, re-export it. you just have to replace several folders in android studio though

Comment: Now I can move to Scene 1 using UnityPlayerActivity.java Button 1. How can I move to scene 2 by clicking Button 2.... See my edit... Eg: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZaqC.png